# Admit contact to journey via API if entry source is Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio, marketingcloudapi

We have a Journey set up with a Data Extension as the entry source with an automation. Now we are exploring the possibilities to admit contacts to the same journey via the API on an ad-hoc basis. So far I have not found any examples of this.

Is there some (un)documented API that allows for this? Or another approach that you would recommend in this scenario?

Comment: Remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only have one entry type per journey. I have previously investigated exactly same use case, where a DE entry also was supposed to be triggered from an API call, and found this not possible.